# DVV/ICC Stage-One Test for the Certification in English

Tags: certification

I've received a CV that includes a certificate on a "DVV/ICC Stage-One Test for the Certification in English". I don't know this test. What is equivalent, e.g. w.r. to the European Framework (A1-C2) or TOEFL score?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting a direct link, but Google turned up a PDF about [TELC](http://www.telc.net) which started from German Adult Education (DVV). "Stage One" appears to be very old terminology as they currently use the European Framework that you mentioned.

Comment: @mkennedy: Thanks. Make an answer out of it, I'll be happy to accept it.